# npm install --save-exact not respecting exact version

Tags: node.js, npm, mjml

My environment:

- node v6.17.1
- npm v6.14.4

I ran `npm install --save --save-exact mjml@4.5.1`, and afterward my `package.json` shows

```
"mjml": "4.5.1",
```

My `package-lock.json` shows:

```
 "mjml": {
      "version": "4.5.1",
      "resolved": "https://npm.alertmd.io/mjml/-/mjml-4.5.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-sQVbQ30UwxMpjzkTPdU9RD5OC9ikEjtZEY+zqAioHXAtEmiO0L0eUdfpcb0ni1pu09hMWU4iqRtOyxLgZIOThg==",
      "requires": {
        "mjml-accordion": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-body": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-button": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-carousel": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-cli": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-column": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-core": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-divider": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-group": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-head": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-head-attributes": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-head-breakpoint": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-head-font": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-head-preview": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-head-style": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-head-title": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-hero": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-image": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-migrate": "4.5.0",
        "mjml-navbar": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-raw": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-section": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-social": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-spacer": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-table": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-text": "4.5.1",
        "mjml-validator": "4.5.0",
        "mjml-wrapper": "4.5.1"
      }
    }
```

Also none of my other dependencies have mjml as a subdependency.

However, when I run `npm show mjml version` I get: `4.6.2`.

I thought using `--save-exact` would install the exact version 4.5.1, so what am I not understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assumption that `--save-exact` will install the exact version (`4.5.1`) is correct.

However, when you utilize the npm [`show`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/view.html) command, i.e. when you run:

```
npm show mjml version
```

you're essentially performing a http `GET` request to the npm registry at `https://registry.npmjs.org/mjml`. The aforementioned command queries the registry/database and returns the latest version of `mjml` which is available in the registry, i.e. version `4.6.2` in this case.

To obtain/check which version of `mjml` has been installed you need to utilize the npm [`ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) command instead.

1. `cd` to your project directory.
2. Then run:

   ```
   npm ls mjml
   ```

   This will print the following to your console:

   > ```
   > └── mjml@4.5.1
   > ```